# Issue with conflicting API Gateways pointing to Lambda in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am newbie to AWS and looking to resolve the API Gateway issue. We had a frontend web application where if users perform any activity by clicking a **Personal Details** link then request will hit the AWS API Gateway "A" and trigger lambda-A. We created AWS code pipeline and deployed application using Cloud Formation Stack which creates new API Gateway-B and Lambda-B. After the deployment it was intended that when ever user hits the **Personal Details** it should hit API Gateway-B and triggering the Lambda-B instead it was hitting old AWS API Gateway "A" and triggering lambda-A. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the base path mapping of your backend domain to API Gateway B.

Or you have to edit the backend url in frontend code to new api gateway url

[Custom domains with API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)

Comment: Hi @Prashanna thanks for your reply. We deployed using the server less lambda architecture. So from the frontend web portal when user clicks on the link it is hitting the old API Gateway instead of new API Gateway B. Do we mention which API Gateway it should hit in frontend? Actually API Gateway is generated on the fly using the sam template.

Comment: Hi @Raghu How/where is your frontend files hosted?. It would be nice if you could provide a simple diagrammatic representation in your question!

Comment: Hi issue got resolved. It was due to the client request redirecting to data power (Third Party service for security). They configured the default gateway to old API Gateway hence the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Lambda function in API Gateway. Please check this article which have screenshots.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

Also I want to recommend you to use Serverless for your project.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the User request from Website navigating to data power (third party vendor for security). In data power it was configured to old API Gateway, so we changed it to new API Gateway.